# Base64 images from SharePoint multi-line text to PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Basically, I am trying to set an Image in Power Apps from a multi-line text field in SharePoint that stores the base64 image.

The multi-line text fields in SharePoint stores the base64 image like **"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU......."**

I upload these images to SharePoint entries from PowerApps by doing a Patch and using this JSON formula `JSON(penFullMapDrawing.Image, JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData)`.

- The base64 image successfully writes to SharePoint and **when I copy and paste the base64 text from SharePoint into the Image property for an Image in PowerApps it displays the proper image**.
- The problem is that **when I try to set the Image property via a LookUp function to retrieve the base64 text from SharePoint the image does not display in PowerApps even though it grabs the correct text**.

Any ideas how to make this work or what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the “s surrounding the base64 image.

I had to modify my LookUp function to Substitute(LookUp(), “”””, “”) and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for you. I am also setting an Image property through **Base64** data, but it is through a JSON call. It returns the following data:

```
{
  "$content-type": "image/png",
  "$content": "iVBORw0...="
}
```

`$content` is Base64 data that I am parsing using `outputs()` into a variable and sending to my canvas app through Power Automate. My image control's Image property is set to that variable, and feeding it the Base64 data directly works fine to update the control. The output from Power Automate looks like this:

`"variable": "iVBORw0...="` This works without the content type tag.

So maybe you could try creating a SharePoint flow rather than using LookUp?

Comment: This seems like a solid solution but I found another workaround closer to my original approach. See my answer for details. Thank you!